# Windows 10 task bar minimum height

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I cannot reduce my task bar more than this:

[image: task bar]

I was using the task bar on the left for a while and it was working correctly but when I decided to put it back on the bottom it became impossible to reduce it more than what you see above.

I tried many things (everything that comes up first on google) but nothing worked.
Except the size problem, everything else works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem came from the "Tools" custom directory (on the right)  which had big icons. Removing the custom directory allowed the bar to get back to the correct (small) size.

Changing the custom directory icons size did not work because the icons where not small enough.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.